# Printing random element of list of strings always gives the same string

Tags: python

I am making a text based game and Im trying to print out a random enemy and it prints the same enemy every time in the output variable

```
import random

monsters = [("Goblin", 1), ("Troll", 3), ("Bear", 2), ("Giant Spider", 1), ("Bandit", 1), ("Wolf", 1), ("Homeless Man", 1), ("Goblin Chief", 3)]

def spawnMonster():
    enemy, DMG = random.choice(monsters)
    print(enemy)
    output = "A " + enemy + " comes out of the bushes."

spawnMonster()
print(output)
```

Comment: Perhaps, `random` likes that enemy. On a serious note, it is random and the same value may occur again and again

Comment: @BhargavRao: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: @MarkRansom https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: How many times did you run your program?

Comment: I printed put enemy and it displayed a random one but the output variable always prints "Goblin"

Comment: @BhargavRao: If it's anything like most computer RPGs, `random` presumably likes the weakest monster whenever you're trying to farm for XP, and the strongest monster whenever you're trying to run back to town to heal up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem with your program has nothing to do with randomness. It's that you're not returning the `output` value from the function to the top level, so whatever you had lying around in `output` before (probably from a previous run of your old program that you're doing in the same interactive session) is never getting changed.

Your old version used `global output`. That works, although it's a bit clunky.

A better solution would be to *return* the value. Like this:

```
def spawnMonster():
    enemy, DMG = random.choice(monsters)
    print(enemy)
    output = "A " + enemy + " comes out of the bushes."
    return output

print(spawnMonster())
```

But if you want it to be a global for some reason, you can go back to that.